# If DeviceCheck is device specific not app specific, so it's possible for another app to mess with the 4 bits?

Tags: ios11, devicecheck

If DeviceCheck is device specific and not app specific, is it possible for another app to mess with the 4 bits and hence mess up your app in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bits are common between apps by a single developer on a device. Your app will not share bits with the Facebook app, for example, but if you produce multiple apps under the same team, they'll share.